# Xamarin AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer transitions

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

I would like to change the animation between page transitions on Android by extending the *NavigationPageRenderer*. However, unlike the *Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.NavigationRenderer*, there aren't any methods for *OnPopToRootAsync*, *OnPopViewAsync*, and *OnPushAsync*. Is it possible to override the transition on a page with the *AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add a custom renderer for the NavigationPageRenderer, and override the SetupPageTransition.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(AnimationNavigationRenderer))]
namespace ProjectName.Droid
{
    public class AnimationNavigationRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void SetupPageTransition(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transaction, bool isPush)
        {
            if (isPush)
                transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_top, 0, 0, Resource.Animation.abc_slide_out_top);
            else
                transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_top, 0, 0, Resource.Animation.abc_slide_out_top);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For more information, check out the Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/NavigationPageRenderer.cs on GitHub (2.3.0 branch) https://github.com/xamarin/

Answer (score 0):

For [Android X](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) use it like this:

```
protected override void SetupPageTransition(AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentTransaction transaction, bool isPush)
```